# How do i jump back to the previous read if left empty

Tags: bash

```
Default_Dir=/export/home/cwatts/test
Default_Log=DB.Audit

echo "Please, enter your Fullname [ENTER]:"
read fname

if [ -z "$fname" ]; then
    echo "Please enter a value!"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Please, enter the Database name [ENTER]:"
    read dbname
    if [ -z "$dbname" ]; then
        echo "Please enter a value!"
    else
        echo "Please, enter a brief Description [ENTER]:"
        read desc
        if [ -z "$desc" ]; then
            echo "Please enter a value!"
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ ! -d $Default_Dir ]; then
    echo "directory doesn't exit, it will be created"
    mkdir $Default_Dir
fi

echo `date -u` $dbname $fname $desc >> $Default_Dir/$Default_Log
exit
```

Comment: You might want to format this code for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
while [ -z "${value-}" ]
do
    echo "Please, enter your Fullname [ENTER]:"
    read value
done
```

Comment: Thanks mate.. Was driving me mad. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding somewhat on l0b0's answer and refactoring for legibility and idiomatic expression:

```
nonempty () {
    test -n "$1" && return 0
    echo "Please enter a value" >&2
    return 1
}

while true; do
    read -p "Please, enter your Fullname [ENTER]: " fname
    nonempty "$fname" || continue
    read -p "Please, enter the Database name [ENTER]: " dbname
    nonempty "$dbname" || continue
    read -p "Please, enter a brief Description [ENTER]:" desc
    nonempty "$desc" || continue
    break
done

date -u +"%c $dbname $fname $desc" >> $Default_Dir/$Default_Log
```

(The hack to put the string you want to echo in the format string of `date` will break if any of the values could contain a percent sign.)

If you are okay with the slightly dubious practice of having a function define global variables for you, the code duplication can still be reduced significantly.

```
accept () {
    read -p "$2 [ENTER]: " "$1"
    test -n "${!1}" && return 0
    echo "Please enter a value" >&2
    return 1
}

while true; do
    accept fname  "Please, enter your Fullname"       || continue
    accept dbname "Please, enter the Database name"   || continue
    accept desc   "Please, enter a brief Description" || continue
    break
done
```

The indirect variable reference `${!var}` is a Bashism, and not portable to other shells.

Comment: Ack @l0b0's answer as the inspiration.

Comment: It would be annoying to have to fill in *all* the parameters again if *any* of them are empty...

Comment: Prompts are annoying either way. Command-line parameters (or a configuration file) would be more user-friendly.